# Finding bases for the eigenspaces of the matrix 3*3

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to find bases for the eigenspaces of the following matrix:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&6&12\\0&3&10\\0&0&-2\end{bmatrix}$$

Can you help me?

Comment: Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

$\lambda=0,3,-2$ eigen values are same as the diagonal entries. Eigen space corresponding to $\lambda=0$ same as the null space. Solve 
$$Ax=3x \tag{1}$$
$$Ax=-2x \tag{1}$$
for the eigen space corresponding to the eigen values $\lambda=3,-2$ respectively.